# Aplicação .NET online + Offline

Tags: c#, .net

É o seguinte, há hoje alguma forma ou ferramenta que permita gravar os dados em um banco offline caso a internet do cliente caia? Vou explicar melhor, a minha aplicação é Web, feita em .Net, roda totalmente do Browser e a princípio, vai gravar tudo no banco online, mas e se a conexão do cliente cair? Eu precisaria que esses dados fossem gravados na máquina do cliente localmente, para quando a conexão voltasse, todos essa informação armazenada localmente fosse lançada no banco de dados online. O que vocês acham?

Obrigado.

Comment: vai virar praticamente uma aplicação desktop então... o problema é, o navegador não tem acesso a um "banco de dados" local por razões de segurança. Os repositórios a disposição do navegador são limitados, pode usar cookies para dados muito pequenos, e localStorage, mas não vai consguir por um banco inteiro do lado cliente

Comment: O nome dessa ferramenta é banco de dados.

Answer (score 1):

Através do JavaScript você pode acessar o [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API), que é uma API do navegador que permite o acesso à um banco de dados local, próprio do *browser*. Há o [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) também, caso deseje armazenar dados mais simples.